# why is wagner being used in this example

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, npm

```
var express = require('express');
var wagner = require('wagner-core');

require('./models')(wagner);
require('./dependencies')(wagner);

var app = express();

wagner.invoke(require('./auth'), { app: app });

app.use('/api/v1', require('./api')(wagner));

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000!');
```

In this code it can be seen while adding a module using require we add `(wagner)`. I don't understand the purpose of this statement. How is this helping with dependency injection?

Comment: What do you mean *"like typecasting"*? You're *calling* the result of `require` and passing `wagner` as a parameter.

Comment: thanks that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is using wager as dependency management.

```
require('./models')(wagner);
```

here wagner is passed so, services created with wagner can be invoked later inside models